# Python feature disabled vim-nox

Tags: vim, python

I have installed `vim-nox` version 7.4 package in my Debian Wheezy machine from backports. I am confused that the python feature still does not work as shown from `vim --version` command as `-python` as well as `-python3`. I have been surfing around and finding a possible solution by purging `vim-tiny` and reinstall `vim-nox`, but it didn't work out.

Here is the output of `dpkg -l vim*`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                  Version                            Architecture Description
+++-=====================================-==================================-============-================================================================================================
ii  vim                                   2:7.4.488-3~bpo70+1                amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
un  vim-athena                            <none>                                          (no description available)
ii  vim-common                            2:7.4.488-3~bpo70+1                amd64        Vi IMproved - Common files
un  vim-doc                               <none>                                          (no description available)
un  vim-gnome                             <none>                                          (no description available)
un  vim-gtk                               <none>                                          (no description available)
un  vim-lua                               <none>                                          (no description available)
ii  vim-nox                               2:7.4.488-3~bpo70+1                amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with scripting languages support
un  vim-perl                              <none>                                          (no description available)
un  vim-python                            <none>                                          (no description available)
un  vim-ruby                              <none>                                          (no description available)
ii  vim-runtime                           2:7.4.488-3~bpo70+1                all          Vi IMproved - Runtime files
un  vim-scripts                           <none>                                          (no description available)
un  vim-tcl                               <none>                                          (no description available)
un  vim-tiny                              <none>                                          (no description available)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem happened due to default path of `vim` goes to `/usr/bin/vim` or `/usr/local/bin/vim`, which does not provide `python` feature, instead of `vim-nox`. I realized this problem by using `which` command to investigate.

Therefore, I simply made an alias for vim as vim.nox.

```
alias vim='vim.nox'
```